# Why does my github runner die after the first succesful run?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, github, amazon-ec2, github-actions

So I want to connect my frontend on aws. For that I chose EC2, and I made a runner for CI, so I don't have to update the code manually every time a change is done. The problem is that if I make a brand-new instance and run the workflow it finishes with a success, but every time after that that I to try the same workflow with the same runner, literally 0 changes (I just delete a comment from a file). The runner after some time dies and the workflow just goes on without doing anything. Also, the connection I made to the EC2 Ubuntu gets very laggy, to the point I can't even add a character.

My pipeline yaml.

```
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "cloud/aws" ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
      
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
        cache-dependency-path: 'app/package-lock.json'

    - name: Install Dependencies
      run: npm install
      working-directory: ./app
    
    - name: Build
      run: npm run build
      working-directory: ./app
```